# How to use apache drill do page search

Tags: apache-drill

i want use apache drill to do a page search. But it just provide a limit key words,I don't know how to write a good sql.Do any anybody can help me?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill supports both [LIMIT](https://drill.apache.org/docs/select-limit/) and [OFFSET](https://drill.apache.org/docs/select-offset/) operators. So, pagination can be achieved using these.

Sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json` order by employee_id LIMIT 20 OFFSET 10 ROWS
```

Some important ponits from Drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/select-offset/#usage-notes):

> - The OFFSET number must be a positive integer and cannot be larger than the number of rows in the underlying result set or no rows are returned.
>     You can use the OFFSET clause in conjunction with the LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses.
> - When used with the LIMIT option, OFFSET rows are skipped before starting to count the LIMIT rows that are returned. If the LIMIT option is not used, the number of rows in the result set is reduced by the number of rows that are skipped.
> - The rows skipped by an OFFSET clause still have to be scanned, so it might be inefficient to use a large OFFSET value.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i know how to do it.

Comment: @xiaoming.lee Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on other questions which still don't have answers.

Comment: Ok i know.Sorry it's my first time to use this.

Comment: No issues @xiaoming.lee..:)