# Apache Drill Query data rertival is not constant on HDFS system

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-drill

I am working on Apache Drill and HDFS in my project.

I am dealing with v.big file (e.g 150GB) and that file is stored in HDFS system. I am writing my Drill query such a way that i will get some amount of data and i will process that (e.g 100 rows) and then again fire a query on that file, so my performance will increase.
(e.g SELECT * FROM dfs.`file path` LIMIT 100 )

But every time when i perform a query on that File which is in HDFS system, i am not getting consistent data. It changes every time as Hadoop will fetch that data from any cluster.

Because of that, it may be the case that during the entire process of getting all the record, i may get the same records which i have already.

Comment: Why would you use LIMIT? Apache Drill will use different threads to access the data, HDFS will provide the data management. So performance issues should be already considered by the platform. LIMIT should only be used if you want to restrict the amount of result rows. Also, there should be some kind of OFFSET if LIMIT is being used.

Comment: I am trying that because i am unable to process whole file at once. It is giving me exception of "OutOfMemory" for that drillbit.

Comment: How much RAM do you have on the Drillbits? How much RAM is configured as heap size for Java? Which Java version is being used?

Comment: I have 4GB of RAM allocated to Drillbit.I am using jdk1.8.

Comment: Well, how much RAM do you have on the node? Could you allocate more?

Comment: No tobi6. I can not. Actually my network team has not given the permission to change the Drill configuration to me.. That is why i am thinking of chunking the data in drill query. I found one solution to the constant data retrieval. That is converting the whole file into drill table. And if i query on that table,every time i am getting constant data. But here again the limitation is Drill is allowing the max table size to be created as 1.3GB and i am dealing with much more bigger files. So not all the data from my file is converting into drill table.

Comment: I see, thank you for your detailed explanation. It might be useful to add this kind of information to the question from the very beginning to let others know the context of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be lucky with using pagination with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, altough I am not sure about it's behaviour with HDFS.

There is a question with a similar approach [How to use apache drill do page search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183523/how-to-use-apache-drill-do-page-search) and the documentation says:

> The OFFSET clause provides a way to skip a specified number of first rows in a result set before starting to return any rows.

([Source](https://drill.apache.org/docs/offset-clause/))

Comment: Thanks tobi for providing your valuable feedback. I tried this option also. But data is not consistent in HDFS. :(

Comment: This really puzzles me. You shouldn't even notice that there are different data nodes providing you with data since the name node is handling all access. What exactly is not consistent? How does your Storage Configuration look like in Drill? (Please [edit] your question)